# What to say when a first year PhD student can't handle basic courses?

Tags: phd, coursework

One of my first-year PhD students wrote to me saying that she is desperate as she is not handling her course load well (she is in the middle of her first semester), and she is afraid she will fail the courses.

There is no possibility of dropping the courses anymore and her funding is strictly dependent on scoring well on these courses.

Do you have any suggestions of what are good responses to this?

Edit: Thank you for your feedback. I think it's probably the case that she is not used to this level of intensity of the courses. I gave her a word of incentive, saying that me and the hiring comittee believed in her potential, so she should also. We also scheduled a face to face meeting.

Comment: If you think she is not an idiot, you can request incompletes or talk to her professors about extensions. If she is in fact an idiot, then there is nothing to do.

Comment: Yes, some incompletes might help.  Also, if she is having health or mental health problems, she may be able to withdraw from one or more classes after the normal deadline. That would probably not resolve the funding issue, though.  // If you believe in her potential, you could help arrange for tutoring.  I have seen this done for a student with potential and it did the trick.

Comment: Tell her it's okay to work in the industry without a PhD. If she's not good enough, then she shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: Have you asked your colleagues?

Comment: Just curious: what kind of calendar do you have where late April is the middle of a semester?

Comment: Had you noticed she was doing badly before she wrote to you?  If so, what were you doing/planning to do, or what had you done, before she wrote?  What safety net detection and procedures does your department have in place?  In general, would you describe your department as sink-or-swim for new grad students? Did the department assign her a temporary advisor? // What type of funding does she have?

Comment: @NateEldredge. 1st semester: Mar-Jun, 2nd semester: Aug-Nov. summer courses in Jan-Feb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest having a **discussion** with the student to see if you can determine together what the issues are and figure out how to address them.  There are many reasons why the student may not be handling her courses well: personal issues, poor preparation, poor study habits, culture shock, etc.  It is also possible that she's not doing worse than other students, but her impression is negative because the courses/material is harder than her undergrad courses.  From what you have said, it's impossible to say whether she'll be able to do fine in the PhD program or not, or how much help she may need, but it certainly sounds like she could use at least some emotional support, if not tactical advice as well.

In addition, as Nate suggest in the comments, it may be helpful to diagnose the issue (for you and/or her) to talk to her instructors to get their impression of her in the courses.  If you have/know some reliable senior grad students, you might also suggest her to talk to them.

Comment: Many PhD students are not good at discussions, especially under pressure.

Comment: @Insulin69 If your students aren't able to have a conversation with you, that's a whole nother issue.

Comment: just putting it out there.